# backbone.js model and collection overhead

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

When I fetch models or collections from the server, I am not able to access properties of the model unless I stringify then re-parse. Presumably the models themselves have some extra overhead from backbone.js? Note that in the below code I can perform stringify/parse sequentially, which is supposed to give the same result as I started with. However, clearly I have killed off some superfluous info by performing these two steps because my model's properties are now exposed differently from before. Surely I do not need to go through these two steps to access my model properties, right?

```
Eg.  
thismodel = /// assume this came from server fetch
alert(thismodel.name);    // DOES NOT WORK - undefined

jsonmodel = JSON.stringify(thismodel);
var providerprefslistJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonmodel);
alert(providerprefslistJSON.name);     // WORKS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone Model objects are not plain old JavaScript objects. They keep their attributes in [an internal hash](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes). To access the `name` attribute you can either do this:

`alert(thismodel.attributes.name);`

Or better yet use [the get() method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get):

`alert(thismodel.get("name"));`

The reason it works when you convert the model to JSON and then back again is because `JSON.stringify` calls [the toJSON() method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON), which creates a JSON string from *the internal attributes hash*, meaning when you parse that string you get a plain old JavaScript object - which is not the same as a Backbone Model object.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you trying to access the property of the model or response?

From `alert(thismodel.name)` it would seem that you're going for a property of the model not the attribute. If you're looking for the model attribute then perhaps you want `alert(this.model.get('name'))`

If you're indeed going for model.name, then basically the problem may lie in how you're parsing the data. Say for example the JSON from your server is like this {'name':'Jimmy'}.

While the `model.response` the raw JSON sent has "Jimmy" namespaced under object.name, Backbone will automatically take that and turn it into a model attribute unless instructed otherwise (e.g. modelObj.attributes.name) at which point you'd use the `get()` function.

You should be able to access model data fairly simply if everything works.

E.g. Fetch

```
var model = new MyModel();
    model.id = 1;
    model.fetch({
        success: function(model, response) {
            console.log(model.get('name'));  // The model name attribute
            console.log(response.name);  // The RAW response name property
        }
    });
```

Or maybe your server isn't sending the data back as JSON data. Is the server response `content-type="application/json"` ?

Some things to check.